# AngularJS directive with ng-model, ng-model will not set

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to apply a directive to an input field, have a callback function, and use `ng-model`. When I use the scope object in the directive, it eliminates the `ng-model` functionality.

```
    var MyCtrl = ['$scope',
    function($scope,){

        $scope.aModel = 'HELLO!';

        $scope.myFunction = function(item){

            $scope.aModel = '';

        };

    }];

app.directive('myDirective',function(){

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            myCallback: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope,element,attrs){

            element.bind('keyup',function(){

                scope.myCallback({item: 'test'});
                });
            }
       }
    });
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" my-directive my-callback="myFunction(item)" ng-model="aModel" />
```

[**Problem Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/fzAISgUa7OCQfWoerPz8?p=preview)

Comment: You have a Typo there. Also, you are trying to update a model with a callback function , but the model is bound to the input control who is triggering that function. what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Calling parent scope method from isolated scope will not run digest cycle, you need run the digest cycle manually.
So there are three ways to do run digest cycle manually, either `scope.$evalAsync`, `$timeout` or `$apply()` for running digest cycle.
Out of which [**`$evalAsync` is better way to run digest cycle**](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2605-scope-evalasync-vs-timeout-in-angularjs.htm), because if any digest is currently in progress then `$scope.$evalAsync()` expressions are placed in an **async queue** that is flushed at the start of each $digest iteration.

While `$apply()` & `$timeout` function execution will conflict with current digest cycle execution.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('myDirective',function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        myCallback: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope,element,attrs){

        element.bind('keyup',function(){
          scope.$evalAsync(function(){
            scope.myCallback({item: 'test'});
          })
        });

    }
}});
```

[**Updated Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/R7UVkOpJvXF9LHlCw9Qn?p=preview)

Comment: Thank You, all answers are excellent. My problems were caused by an outdated version of angular. Sorry for the wasted efforts.

Comment: but you must need to do scope.$evalAsync / $timeout to update binding, you can accept answer if it does helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scope.$apply` (see this **[updated Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/n0QuD5iQ75NRTm82SNHp?p=preview)**):

```
app.directive('myDirective',function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        myCallback: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope,element,attrs){

        element.bind('keyup',function(){

            scope.$apply(function() {
              scope.myCallback({item: 'test'});
            });


        });

    }
}});
```

Since you're using an isolate scope, the function happens outside the context of the controller, and the model isn't updated unless you force a new digest cycle.

Comment: Thank You, all answers are excellent. My problems were caused by an outdated version of angular. Sorry for the wasted efforts.

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
app.directive('myDirective',['$timeout', function($timeout){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        myCallback: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope,element,attrs){
        element.bind('keyup',function(){
           $timeout(function() {
               scope.myCallback({item: 'test'});
           },10) 
        });
    }
}});
```

`$timeout` calls $apply phase automatically.

```
AntiPattern
```

Check `$scope.$$phase` and call `$scope.$apply()` explicitly.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
var MyCtrl = ['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.aModel = 'HELLO!';
    $scope.myFunction = function(item){
        $scope.aModel = item;
        if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();
    };
}];

app.directive('MyCtrl',MyCtrl);

app.directive('myDirective',function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        myCallback: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope,element,attrs){
        element.bind('keyup',function(){
            scope.myCallback({item: 'test'});
        });
    }
}});
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/R7UVkOpJvXF9LHlCw9Qn?p=preview)**

Comment: why to follow angular antipatterns https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Anti-Patterns

Comment: Thank You, all answers are excellent. My problems were caused by an outdated version of angular. Sorry for the wasted efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I had an outdated version of Angular. Thought I was losing it. Upgraded to v1.2.27 and everything was solved. My original code works fine. Thank you for all the answers.

Comment: I believe, added plunkr is also of angular 1.2.27 which is not working

Comment: It doesn't work with 1.2.17 plunkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/fzAISgUa7OCQfWoerPz8?p=preview, how you got it worked

Comment: I also needed the AngularJS 'ngRoute' library as well

Comment: but how did it works without `$scope.$evalAsync` ? can you please get it working inside plunkr